# Unexpected behavior in concurrency (Java)

Tags: java, concurrency

I have written the simplest source to reproduce the problem as follows

```
package concurrency.test;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Main().start();
    }

    private void start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(new SequencePrinter(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
    }

    private class SequencePrinter implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println( IdGenerator.instance().nextId());
        }
    }

    private static class IdGenerator
    {
        private static IdGenerator instance;
        private final AtomicLong idSequence = new AtomicLong( 0 );

        private IdGenerator()
        {
        }

        public static IdGenerator instance ()
        {
            if ( instance == null )
            {
                instance = new IdGenerator();
            }

            return instance;
        }

        synchronized public long nextId ()
        {
            return idSequence.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

What I expect: Unique ids in no order

What I have found: Multiple 1s (any other number is unique but not '1')

It looks like I have not understood some basic concepts of concurrency. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `instance()` method of your class `IdGenerator` is not thread-safe, so multiple instances of this class might be created, each with their own `idSequence` member variable, when multiple threads call the method concurrently.

You'll need to make the `instance()` method thread-safe, for example by making it `synchronized`.

Comment: Thanks that was easy :) I feel ashamed

Comment: Indeed, I think that he wanted to place keyword `synchronized` as modifier for getInstance but got it for `inc`, which does not make any sence.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of synchronizing synchronized increment? Next time, always, use `static Type singlenote = new ...` to create singletones.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class SequencePrinter implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("produces " + idSequence.incrementAndGet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new SequencePrinter(), 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    private static final AtomicLong idSequence = new AtomicLong( 0 );

}
```

The code becomes much simpler and buts eliminated. Might be you wanted to create instance in the getNext and that is why you sunchronized it? Do not create tons of useless getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. The check-then-act in the `instance` method is a race condition, which needs to be atomic.

```
if (instance == null) {
    instance = new IdGenerator();                
}
```

Secondly, the `idSequence` is an atomicLong, so it doesn't need to be synchronized.

```
private static class IdGenerator
    {
        private static IdGenerator instance;
        private final AtomicLong idSequence = new AtomicLong( 0 );
        private static Object lock = new Object();

        private IdGenerator()
        {
        }

        public static IdGenerator instance ()
        {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new IdGenerator();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public long nextId ()
        {
            return idSequence.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```